# Notation for multiplying elements in a vector

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If you have some column vectors called $A$, $B$, and $C$ (all with the same number of rows), of the following form...

$A = \begin{pmatrix}
a_1 \\
a_2 \\
\vdots \\
a_n \\
\end{pmatrix} ,\hspace{1 cm} 
B = \begin{pmatrix}
b_1 \\
b_2 \\
\vdots \\
b_n \\
\end{pmatrix} , \hspace{1 cm} 
C = \begin{pmatrix}
c_1 \\
c_2 \\
\vdots \\
c_n \\
\end{pmatrix}$

Is there any particular notation or name for the operation that produces a vector of the same length looking like the following?

$D= \begin{pmatrix}
a_1b_1c_1 \\
a_2b_2c_2 \\
\vdots \\
a_nb_nc_n \\
\end{pmatrix}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Element-wise multiplication is quite descriptive and is being used by the MATLAB community. This can also be used for matrices.

Comment: Great, thanks. The word 'element-wise' got me to this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20412/element-wise-or-pointwise-operations-notation I guess this has been asked many times before!