# Multiply $1\times 3$ matrix by corresponding numbers

Tags: linear-algebra

For example, I want to this to happen:
$$\begin{bmatrix}1& 2& 3\end{bmatrix}\times\begin{bmatrix}2& 3& 4\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}2& 6& 12\end{bmatrix}$$
It's not exactly matrix multiplication, but I hope you can see what I'm getting at. Is there some notation in linear algebra that allows this function to be valid?

Comment: Use MathJax to clarify your ideas.

Comment: See [Element-wise (or pointwise) operations notation?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/20412/345849)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe what you are describing is called the Hadamard product. You can read about them and see some notation for using them on the Wikipedia page. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)

This page uses the notation $\circ$ for the Hadamard product.

Comment: That is what I know it as.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know any standard matrix operation of this kind. You can rewrite the three entries of the $1\times 3$ matrices as diagonal elements of a $3 \times 3$ matrix, than perform the standard matrix multiplication.