# Matrix notation for element-wise raising to the power of $n$

Tags: matrices, notation, hadamard-product

The [Hadamard product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)) $A \odot B$ gives the element-wise multiplication of matricies $A$ and $B$.

How do I denote the raising a matrix to the power $n$, element-wise?

Answer (score 7):

[Wikipedia's Hadamard Analogous operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)#Analogous_operations) gives the following notation for raising each element of $A$ to the power of $n$:

$$\huge{A^{\circ n}}$$

This is called the "Hadamard power" for which Google has 2,960 results, or perhaps "Hadamard exponentiation" (19 google results).

Comment: which may come as surprise (to me at last). For maps, the notation $f^{\circ n}$ is often used when one needs to distinguidh iteration from product, i.e., $f^{\circ 3}(x)=f(f(f(x)))$ vs. $f^3(x)=f(x)\cdot f(x)\cdot f(x)$. Then again, (non-Hadamard) matrix multiplication (and hence power) already corresponds to composition / iteration of linear maps ...

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Perhaps the `\odot` or $\odot$ operator is a better choice then? See [this discussion](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/601545/389109) on Hadamard notation.